# find distinct record values for a field from elastic search query instead of count of distinct

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I need distinct records from elastic search query like we do in database as

`select distinct(title) from tablename`

instead of

`select count(distinct(title)) from tablename`

I have used aggregation but it does not solve my problem because it gives only count , i need some search filter or anything else that give me result like this,
if i have 3 records:

```
id   title    
1    ab is
2    sdf sdf
3    ab is
```

and then i fetch from query it gives me output as :

```
hits : [
   1 : ab is
   2 : sdf sdf
]
```

query i am applying is

```
{ "query": {
    "match" : {"title" : "sing alongs"}
  },
 "from": 0,
 "aggs": {
   "genres": {
     "terms": {
       "field": "title"
      }
    }
 },
 "size": 30,
 "_source": [  
   "title"   
 ]}
```

and result i am getting is

```
{
{
  "_index": "events",
  "_type": "Activity",
  "_id": "F-m5MGABRY8M87iCVeBZ",
  "_score": 21.652287,
  "_source": {
  "title": "Sing Alongs"
}
} ,
{
  "_index": "events",
  "_type": "Activity",
  "_id": "6OuBwmABRY8M87iCPxNh",
  "_score": 9.333357,
  "_source": {
    "title": "Sing Along"
  }
},
{
  "_index": "events",
  "_type": "Activity",
  "_id": "Q-mEIWABRY8M87iC7Ytl",
  "_score": 9.320941,
  "_source": {
    "title": "Sing-Through"
  }
}
```

}

record with title

> sing alongs

should appear only once here

Answer (score 0):

Use size=1. I don't recognize your query language or the environment you work in, but here is the documentation for using 'size' in a query:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: if i use size = 1 , it will give only 1 record , i need a solution that gives all records but the records with same title should be shown once only , not repeatedly , just as we get result by db query , select distinct(title) from table_name

Comment: i dont understand what you are trying to do, can you give an example with an input and expected output? i mean what you need? the entire record, or just a field? also i dont have much experience in sql, im not sure i would understand those examples. and pls show your current query

Comment: i have updated my question for you , kindly read question again.

Comment: i did read it and i'm somewhat closer, but you haven't told me if you need only that field (implying you have multiple fields in a different setting), or you need the first record (by some sorting) for each title.

Comment: actually i mistakenly added some records twice or even thrice when i was adding data in elastic-search , some records are added twice some are added thrice , if a record exists twice or thrice , i need to get it once whether it fetches first occurrence or last or random

Comment: then i think you rather need a db cleanup then a unique result query. try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574868/elasticsearch-remove-duplicates-from-index  right now i can't check it out, but it seems promising